# hardship withdrawal

Tags: united-states, 401k, debt

I am single and have one income. I live in Denver and the rents have gotten crazy here. My rent is now the same as one out of my two bring-home paychecks in a month. I have great credit. I have 25K in credit card debt and 3 grand in medical debt because of cancer treatment. I do not know when the medical bills will stop due to this type of condition. I have been a federal employee for 18 years. I have a negative cash flow every month because I am suffocating trying to pay the minimum payments and everyone has their hand out.

I only have 88K in my 401k. I want to move to another state and buy a house there where the cost of living is not so high and get a fixed rate because the rents here increase 200 a month every renewal.

Trying to pay the credit cards off is no longer seeming possible because half my payments are interest. I am no longer using them, but they are not going down.

Because of my health condition, I would like to take a position in another state , closer to my family and that has a better cost of living than Colorado. I want to have a house built there. It takes 6 months.
I am considering doing a hardship withdrawal for these reasons:

1. I figure I will need 6 grand to have an extra 1k a month for 6 months in addition to my full-time income from my full time job just to pay minimum payments on all medical and credit card debts and living costs.
2. 2 grand for moving across many states
3. 1K to cover deposits, application to apply at apartment in the new state until the house is built
4. 3K in earnest money to sign a contract on a house in new state
5. 9K I borrowed from friends because my cash flow is negative
6. $2900 to vacate my lease early - that is their penalty

I only bring home about 2800- 3000 a month. That is my net. I am on a special diet due to the health condition and take special vitamins, organic produce, etc.

I was fine and had no credit card debt until 5 years ago. Everything got very expensive, especially housing.

I would love to just take out a loan or even a residential loan from my 401K, but that would lower my income substantially to where I don't think I could pay a mortgage. I am 51 years old. Please don't ask me why I have not bought a house before now. I have always wanted to move to another state. Close to my family and less expensive and then I got into cc debt when houses and rents and medical expenses came along. I have a major cash flow problem. I have never been late for any payment at any time my entire life and all my good credit seems to have been for nothing - at my age.

Comment: Your 401 amounts are shielded from bankruptcy. Just putting it out there, in case you didn't know.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I still need a place to live and you can't rent or buy anything with bankruptcy's bad credit.

Comment: If anyone could help me with alternative ways than raiding my retirement and paying huge penalty and 25% tax bracket, I would be very grateful for the advice.

Comment: Buying the house, and especially building a new one (do you already own the land?) - may not really be considered as "hardship". While I understand the desire, and in the long term it will probably be economically justified, in the short term - your primary goal should be reducing the cash outflow, i.e.: finding as cheap accommodation as possible. Buying, and especially *building* a house - is not the cheapest accommodation in the short term.

Comment: In Denver, the rents are identical to mortgages. I am in a tiny 1 BR and I am paying more than all the people I work with who bought houses 10 years ago. Denver's housing situation changed about 2 years ago (law of supply and demand) and thousands are moving in every month. Builders are having trouble finding land.

Comment: I spent 3 weeks with a realtor driving around Denver and we discovered that the ones built in 1986 were the same in price as the new, smaller ones. In the state where I would like to move , the brand new builds are $ 195K and low $200,000s - something you don't find in Denver.

Comment: I did not want a house built in the 60s or 70s in Denver, because I am unable to deal with major repairs emotionally or financially.

Comment: The land is included in the price, high 100's and low 200's in the other state.

Comment: I have never taken a vacation or been extravagant. I basically pay bills and buy commodities. I do not see how I could save money by buying an older house, when the new ones are already in the low 200's out of state. If you don't mind, please clarify. I have never bought a house so I admit I am inexperienced. All lenders approve me because I have good credit, even though I have a high debt to income ratio.

Comment: Houses in my current city went up in value 11 - 35% in 1 year. What if I bought the house here? How long would I have to own it before I could make a little money in equity and sell?

Comment: Buying a house to live in is **not** an investment. My point is that buying is, on the short term, more expensive than renting. And building, on the short term, is more expensive than buying. Maintenance costs do not significantly differ between a new house and an old house, especially if the new house was build by a cheap builder and the old house was well maintained. I suggest, when you move out of state, to find the cheapest rental possible, or live with your family, until your financials and health stabilize.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I have been renting for 20 years. And, honestly, the rents and mortgages are identical in Denver. The exception is the population who bought houses 10 years ago. They are paying many hundreds of dollars less a month for 1500 square feet homes they own than I am in my tiny rental. I get no tax breaks for renting, either. Denver has taken to gouging renters, as well. Going up hundreds of dollars every renewal. I applied for jobs close to my family, but after a year I have received offers 3 hours away, making moving in with family impossible.

Comment: I checked every rental within 50 miles of the job offer and they are about a grand a month. The cheapest base rent is 870 and they add on for water, sewer, trash and washer/dryer usage. I would love to move in with family, if they were nearby :(  I am glad to be getting closer to them with my condition, however. They do not fly. Only drive.

Answer (score 4):

Gaining traction is your first priority.

- 25K credit card balance
- 3K medical debt
- 88K 401k

**WARNING:** as @JosephZambrano explains in his answer the **tax penalty for withdrawing from a 401(k) can easily exceed the APR of the credit card** making it a very bad strategy. Consult in-depth with a financial advisor to see before taking that path.  As @JoeTaxpayer has noted a loan is another alternative.

The 401k is no good to you if you can't have shelter or comfort in the mean time.  The idea is to look at all the money as a single thing and balance it together.  There is no credit and retirement, just a single target that you can hit by moving the good money to clear the bad.

Consolidating the credit card debt somehow would be very wise if you can.  Assuming it is 30% APR shrinking that quickly is the first priority.

You may be able to justify a hardship withdrawal to finance the reduction/consolidation of the credit card.  It may be worth considering negotiating a closure arrangement with a reduced principal.  Credit card companies can be quite open to this as it gets their money back.

You may also be able to negotiate a lower interest rate.

You may be able to negotiate a non-credit-affecting debt consolidation with a debt consolidator.  They want to make money and a 25K loan to a person with sound credit is a pretty good bet.

Moving, buying a house, or any of that may just relocate the problem.

You may be able to withdraw $25K from your 401k under hardship, pay the credit card, and come up with a payment plan for the medical debt.

It's a retirement setback for sure, but retirement is an illusion with that credit card shark eating all of your hard-earned money.  You gotta slay that beast quick.

Again, be sure to fully analyze whether the penalty on the 401(k) withdrawal exceeds the APR of the credit card.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to ponder over everything you said and see what I can do. I love it that you explained seeing it all as a single target. For sure, there is NO retirement nor rest with credit cards. Evil. Pure evil to get bound up. Worse than jail. Bondage is what it is. It must be slayed before it slays me even more than it already has. You have very good solutions.

Comment: Alain, please see my answer as to why Sherry cannot take a hardship withdrawal (yet)

Comment: @JosephZambrano my grasp of US tax law is extremely limited. I had to liquidate my 401(k) when I moved to Canada and I took a big hit on it.  Your answer is well researched.  Thank you.

Comment: Anytime! I am a pension actuary so I have lots of hands on experience with it. Your game plan is spot on - kill the high APR debt first.

Comment: @SherryB. speak with a financial advisor about the best strategy here. I'm good on high level concepts, but not the ins and outs of tax law and withdrawal penalties. Joseph Zambrano addresses that nicely in his answer. It has a very important impact on the real capital you have to work with. I got burned withdrawing RRSPs to pay credit cards because I didn't assess the penalties properly. I came out okay, but less well off than I could be.

Comment: -1, sorry. Say she could take the withdrawal. 25% federal tax, say 5% for state, 10% penalty. A 40% hit, vs the loan Joseph suggests. This is a case where the loan might make sense as a stop gap measure. If she loses her job, she's no worse off for trying.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer that's legit. I didn't properly investigate or suggest in-depth investigation of the penalty effect. My main strategy is move high interest debt to low interest debt, but the penalty is effectively an extremely high interest rate.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I've made a clear note of my error above. Does that address your concern?

Comment: Yes. DV reversed. +1

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the 401(k). Before taking a hardship withdrawal, one must first deplete the ability to take any 401(k) loans available. This is a regulation. The 401(k) loan limit is the lesser of $50k, 50% your vested balance, or $50k minus the highest loan balance within the last year. Here's the good news: it is not a taxable event; you can pay back over a maximum of 5 years; interest is low (usually 4.25% or so). The bad news: if you terminate employment then the loan balance must be repaid or else it becomes taxable income plus a 10% penalty. I suggest you consider eliminating the credit card debt via this option. Pay back as aggressively as possible and if/when you terminate you can take the 10% penalty - it will be far less of an impact than 25k accruing approximately 25% annually.

Comment: My head is spinning. I am so stressed out. May I say this: I desperately want to move to the south to be near my aging parents. They need me there. I love them and want to be near them at this time. This is extremely important to me. How do I find a financial advisor? Would a tax consultant be a horrible choice? Let me ask you about this option: What about my moving to the south and taking the hardship withdrawal because I have no cash to move and then buying a house in the south and then after closure, filing bankruptcy so I will be able to buy the house while my credit is good and be able to

Comment: make the mortgage payments and have a house before I am too old. Your thoughts? I am totally desperate.

Comment: I may have to live in the other state for a number of months to be eligible for bankruptcy. My medical bills keep increasing and I have not even started my radiation. I may not even get the radiation. It is 35 dollars every day for 33 days. I have an US this Wednesday and my copay is $100.00.  I just looked at my lease and it demands 3 months of monthly rent if I break the lease. The lease is $1450 and I only receive 2 paychecks a month in the amount of $1500 net pay each.

Comment: You see, without even skimming the top off the credit card debt, it would require:

Comment: the $23,500. That is not including the penalty of 10% and the 25% tax burden.

Comment: I must move because of family. Outside of taking the hardship, I do not see how I can financially do it. If I take a loan out, it must be paid within 5 years. The deductions out of my paychecks to cover this loan over 5 years would likely make paying a needed mortgage an impossibility. I also would need to get a residential loan. I will need to take a smaller residential loan to cover the closing costs and a small down payment on the home. Those can be repaid over 15 years, so I can do that, but only on a small amount of money, like 15K.

Comment: If I take out a hardship, I may only be left with about 10K to put on a house. The one good thing in my favor is my good credit. All lenders approve me. It is sad to have spent over 18 years working at the same occupation and paying everything and having good credit and to not be able to buy a house. I need the protection of a fixed mortgage.

Comment: Sherry, I suggest you consult a tax advisor as they can offer specific advice. (And to that effect, all things I say on this post are a matter of opinion, not to be construed with fact or advice). The point I was making is that it is not possible to take a hardship from your 401(k) without using your loan option first.

Comment: That was my first choice, until I started using the 401K loan calculator to see how it would affect my income. I am in a negative cash flow and I need to move and buy a house. I tried calculating all the credit card and medical debt in with the down payment and closing costs together on the residential loan to repay over 15 years and  saw that it dramatically lowered my take-home pay. It left me without enough money to pay a monthly mortgage or even monthly rent. Then, I would be back with more credit card debt because I would not have enough to live on with what was left over.

Comment: If I took a different position in the occupation where I work in order to transfer to the state I wish to live, I would make less money. Assuming, I brought home $2800 a month, instead of $3,000 and then I took out a 43K residential loan , which will cost me $129 every 2 weeks, which adds up to $258 for most months, and leaves me with approx. $2500 to pay a mortgage and living expenses. That might be possible.. if I filed for bankruptcy after getting a mortgage. It sure beats 40% hardship hit. Houses where I am looking to buy are much less expensive and maybe your idea is the best one for me.

Comment: If I took a different position in the occupation where I work in order to transfer to the state I wish to live, I would make less money. If I brought home $2800 a month, instead of $3,000 and took out a 43K residential loan , with repayment of $129 every 2 weeks, which adds up to $258 for most months, that would leave me with approx. $2500 to pay a mortgage and living expenses. That might be possible.. if I filed for bankruptcy after getting a mortgage. It sure beats 40% hardship hit. Houses where I am looking to buy are much less expensive and maybe your idea is the best one for me.